# How Restsharp is better than HTTPClient?

Tags: rest, .net-core, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I have searched for the various Rest API library to consume REST API in .net core 2.0.
I found that HTTPWebRequest is the original class provided by .net.
WebClient is wrapper of HTTPWebrequest.
RestSharp implementation is easy than HTTPClient.
I am confused which library should I use and which support .net core 2.0 .

Comment: Hey! These type of questions are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow since they are opinion based. But basically RestSharp provides a wrapper on top of .net classes that makes it a bit easier to use when dealing with JSON based API.

Comment: I guess any concrete comparisons can make this thread back-to-topic successfully.